# Planetary gearing

Tags: mechanical

It is said when a planet gear revolves around a fixed sun wheel, the number of revolution it makes might be more than what appears to be logical. For example, if the planet and sun are fitted with 20 and 40 teeth respectively, the planet will rotate three times as it travels around the circumference of the sun wheel. Why three not two? Is there an explanation or formulae for this?

Comment: Have you found any information or formulae for epicyclic gears?

Answer (score 1):

It's one more than you think due to the gear going around.  So 2 due to the teeth ratio, +1 for going around.